# Ruby gsub function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

I'm trying to create a BBcode [code] tag for my rails forum, and I have a problem with the expression:

```
param_string.gsub!( /\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/im, '<pre>\1</pre>' )
```

How do I get what the regex match returns (the text inbetween the [code][/code] tags), and escape all the html and some other characters in it?

I've tried this:

```
param_string.gsub!( /\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/im, '<pre>' + my_escape_function('\1') + '</pre>' )
```

but it didn't work. It just passes "\1" as a string to the function.

Comment: Have you tried double quotes (`"\1"`)?

Comment: Yes, didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take care of the greedy behavior of the regular expressions. So the correct code looks like this:

```
html.gsub!(/\[(\S*?)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/) { |m| escape_method($1, $2) }
```

The `escape_method` then looks like this:

```
def escape_method( type, string )
  case type.downcase
    when 'code'
      "<pre>#{string}</pre>"
    when 'bold'
      "<b>#{string}</b>"
    else
       string
  end
end
```

Comment: as you can see this code can be extended to support every BBcode tag

Comment: That's a great advice, should speed things up a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Someone here posted an answer, but they've deleted it.

I've tried their suggestion, and made it work with a small change. Whoever you are, thanks! :)

Here it is

```
param_string.gsub!( /\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/im ) {|s| '<pre>' + my_escape_function(s) + '</pre>' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `"<pre>#{$1}</pre>"` for your replacement value.