# How do I modify \1 in gsub?

Tags: ruby, regex, redcloth

When I see some text that matches my pattern, I want to create a link to an external site using RedCloth that has a query link for it.

If I have something like:

```
Text 123 1234 12345
```

When I see that I want to replace it with:

```
"Text 123 1234 12345":http://site.com/query?value=Text%20123%201234%2012345
```

If I let it keep the spaces, RedCloth won't notice this as a link correctly.

Here is where I am at:

```
s = "this is a string which has Text 123 1234 12345 "

s = s.s.gsub(/(Text \d+ \d+ \d+)/,'"\1":http://site.com/query?value=\1'

=> "Text 123 1234 12345":http://site.com/query?value=Text 123 1234 12345"
```

The probem is that RedCloth stops parsing after:

```
 "Text 123 1234 12345":http://site.com/query?value=Text
```

So I really need:

```
"Text 123 1234 12345":http://site.com/query?value=Text%20123%201234%2012345"
```

Is there a way I can mess with `\1` in the right hand side of `gsub`, such that I could get the following?  If not, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you want `gsub` to escape the spaces:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991945/ruby-gsub-function

Comment: Thats a good example, which got me to this one    which is how i solved it     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288573/1-and-1-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the comment by Narfanator I found the following: "[$1 and \1 in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288573/1-and-1-in-ruby)".

The solutions was super easy:

```
s = "this is a string which has Text 123 1234 12345 "
s = s.s.gsub(/(Text \d+ \d+ \d+)/){|x| "\"" + x + "\":https://site.com/query?value=" + CGI::escape(x)}
```